# Regex replace some string with pattern

Tags: regex

I have string like this

```
296#2014-06-24,1774#2014-04-14,344#2014-04-14,.......
```

and want result like

```
2014-06-24,2014-04-14,2014-04-14,.......
```

anybody can help me how to get result string with regex? thank you

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search: `\d+#`

Replace:  empty string

**Explanation**

- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- `#` matches a hash
- we replace with the empty string

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify a language, I'm going to use the regex syntax implemented in Java, Perl, JavaScript, and many other languages.
You want to replace all instances of `\d+#` with an empty string (equivalent to deletion). The `\d+` matches one or more digits.

Java Implementation:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\d+#", "");
```

Perl Implementation:

```
$str =~ s/\d+#//g;
```

JS Implementation:

```
str = str.replace(/\d+#/g, '');
```